# SQL Server Foreign key with triggers used as history logger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

Here is my situation. I am working with ASP.NET MVC 5.

My requirement is to track add/update/delete operations on records into history tables.

This example has 2 tables A and B for original records and another tables, AHistories and BHistories for saving the history. There is a one-to-many relationship, one A and many Bs.

I use trigger to implement this. I am stuck with things related to foreign keys. When I insert records into history table in trigger, I want to save the record with foreign keys pointing to IDs in history tables and not from the original tables.

This is what I do in trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER A_History_Trigger ON A FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @AHistoryID INT

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @HistoryType NVARCHAR(6)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted)
        SET @HistoryType = 'update'
    ELSE
        SET @HistoryType = 'add'

    /* Save record from table A into AHistories table */
    INSERT INTO AHistories (HistoryID, Area, ModifiedDate, HistoryType)
    SELECT ID, Area, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @HistoryType
    FROM Inserted

    /* Save updated record from table B into BHistories table */
    IF @HistoryType = 'update'
        INSERT INTO BHistories (HistoryID, AHistoryID, Name, ModifiedDate, HistoryType)
        SELECT ID, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), Name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @HistoryType
        FROM B
        WHERE AID = (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
END
ELSE /* Delete */
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AHistories (HistoryID, Area, ModifiedDate, HistoryType)
    SELECT ID, Area, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'delete' FROM Deleted

    DECLARE @AID INT
    SET @AID = (SELECT ID FROM Deleted)
    SET @AID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    /* B */
    INSERT INTO BHistories (HistoryID, AHistoryID, Name, ModifiedDate, HistoryType)
    SELECT ID, @AHistoryID, Name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'delete'
    FROM B
    WHERE AID = @AID

    DELETE FROM B WHERE AID = @AID
END
```

In trigger for table B,

```
CREATE TRIGGER B_History_Trigger ON B FOR INSERT AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @AHistoryID INT

/* Is this safe? */
SET @AHistoryID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM AHistories WHERE HistoryID = (SELECT TOP 1 AID FROM Inserted) ORDER BY ID DESC)

INSERT INTO BHistories (HistoryID, Name, AHistoryID, ModifiedDate, HistoryType)
SELECT ID, Name, @AHistoryID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'add' FROM Inserted
```

In trigger for B, is it safe to get the correct AHistoryID by performing a SELECT there? In production, I am concerned if there is a case that when multiple users perform actions at the same time that the triggers would SELECT the wrong AHistoryID. Is this acceptable approach?

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: If you can have multiple people accessing a table, assume it will be.  And your ids should still be pointing to the "original" ones anyways - if you change them, it destroys the history (how do you know which id it came from?).  I might not even have a unique id for those tables - generally you don't care about updating/deleting specific rows, you care about the overall history.  So you're running `SELECT` statements that either get all rows (with their timestamp, which is likely unique...), or something more complicated where the id doesn't matter anyways (most-recent-change, say).

Comment: In my history tables, I have unique ID and HistoryID fields where HistoryID is the ID of the original record. When I update A, I want to know which B records that A record had at that update. That way, I could always see what Bs it was pointing to. Am I missing a point?

Comment: Often you'd reconstitute it using the audit timestamps.  Which you should also be able to use to get the audit unique ids.  If you are storing derived fks like this, you want to store them in _addition_ to the original fks.  Your tigger is also not safe for multi-row use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**:

The only issue I can see in your triggers is that you are assuming the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables have just one row.

This assumption will cause error in the first trigger in  this line:

```
WHERE AID = (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
```

if there are more than one row inserted using one `INSERT` statement.

In the second trigger you've covered this issue by selecting `TOP 1`, but that will bring you some bugs because it will choose `AHistories.ID` for one of the rows inserted and save it for all other rows into `BHistories`.

**Solution**:

You can always join the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables to get anything you need. Here are the changes:

```
INSERT INTO BHistories (HistoryID, AHistoryID, Name, ModifiedDate, HistoryType)
SELECT B.ID, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), B.Name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @HistoryType
FROM B
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.ID = B.AID
```

And:

```
INSERT INTO BHistories (HistoryID, AHistoryID, Name, ModifiedDate, HistoryType)
SELECT B.ID, @AHistoryID, B.Name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'delete'
FROM B
INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.ID = B.AID
```

And the last one. Remote this line:

```
SET @AHistoryID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM AHistories WHERE HistoryID = (SELECT TOP 1 AID
```

And update the query like this:

```
INSERT INTO BHistories (HistoryID, Name, AHistoryID, ModifiedDate, HistoryType)
SELECT i.ID, i.Name, ah.ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'add' 
FROM Inserted i
INNER JOIN AHistories ah ON ah.HistoryID = i.AID
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks very good. However, I just gave up on approach with triggers because it was complex for my skill level and time to make it work with all the other tables' relationships. I have changed my approach to track history records in controllers by adding the records to history tables right after its add/update/remove operation. I am also deleting records that are referenced by foreign key instead of having ON DELETE CASCADE. Could I have your thoughts on this?

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Triggers always add complexity to the business and complex triggers make that worse. About cascading deletes, that is also better be replaced by data-layer codes except in some situations where the structure is simpler or the Database is being manipulated by more than a single Application.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. My concern with this approach is since I'm executing code to delete cascade records, what if the user loses connection to the website before the code is done deleting. This will not be a public site, it's going to be used as a admin system, so I expect less traffic. The database is only used for this application. You say "except ... structure is simpler" because it is more safe to let the database do it to avoid failures in code?

Comment: Of course it is safer for the database to do these tasks, but it will bring more complications and become harder to maintain when it grows in size. About your concert about the incomplete operations: you can always `BEGIN` a transaction from inside the code, and if something unexpected happens before the transaction is committed, the Database engine will `ROLLBACK` the incomplete transactions.

Comment: Thanks! Implementing Begintransaction and Rollback helped.